# Updating a card with a onEdit() trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm working on a google App Script add-on and I would like it to change the Card my add-on is showing when a value on my spreadsheets changes, is that posible?

I've tried with this:

```
function onEdit(e) {


     var card=CardService
     .newCardBuilder()
     .setHeader(
         CardService.newCardHeader()
             .setTitle('test')
             .setSubtitle('Check out these widgets')
             .setImageStyle(CardService.ImageStyle.SQUARE)
             .setImageUrl(
                 'https://www.example.com/images/headerImage.png'))
     .addSection(
          CardService.newCardSection()
              .setHeader('Simple widgets')  // optional
              .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(
                  'These widgets are display-only. ' +
                  'A text paragraph can have multiple lines and ' +
                  'formatting.'))
              .addWidget(CardService.newImage().setImageUrl(
                  'https://www.example.com/images/mapsImage.png')))
     .addCardAction(CardService.newCardAction().setText('Gmail').setOpenLink(
         CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl('https://mail.google.com/mail')));

   try {       
          let nav = CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(card.build());
           return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
            .setNavigation(nav)
            .build();
            
    }catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);
    }
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah I don't think that will work.  Where is your buildAddon(e) and where do you return cards too.  I don't think it's the correct environment.

Comment: On this file I use a function to generate it defined on the appsscript.json and it works well, Its the same card as there but changing the title.  What do you mean by buildAddon(e)

Comment: I should have asked what is your "onTriggerFunction".  Perhaps you can share your appsscript.json file