# Update card in response to installable trigger

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm writing a Google Workspace add-on (designed for Sheets) that should be responsive to edits in the spreadsheet. To start, I'm trying to update a Card to show the row and column of the most recent edit. (Eventually I'll add the real functionality I need which includes sending updates to an outside service.)

I've created an installable `onEdit` trigger which I confirmed through log statements is correctly firing, and I'm saving the row and column info in the `DocumentProperties` (also confirmed is working using log statements).

However, I can't figure out how to update the Card in response to this trigger. The [card navigation guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/navigation) only describes how to update cards in response to clicking on a widget *inside* the add-on interface. I'm trying to update in response to an edit in the spreadsheet. Is that even possible?

Things I've tried:

- Returning a built card from the function called by the `onEdit` trigger

Previous questions on StackOverflow seem to have been abandoned without a definitive answer, e.g.

- [Updating a card with a onEdit() trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74815034/updating-a-card-with-a-onedit-trigger)
- [Is it possible to refresh the Google Workspace Add-on sidebar card from installable trigger function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328799/is-it-possible-to-refresh-the-google-workspace-add-on-sidebar-card-from-installa)

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to initiate an interaction with a card.  Like an HTML dialog it must initiate the interaction.  And in the case of Drive there are no update triggers.  Google is real careful about distributing triggers that can be used in DDoS attacks.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestion as to how I could implement a somewhat responsive interface for this? I also don't see time-based triggers available, but I'd love for the card to be able to "refresh" itself as the spreadsheet content changes. Or am I forced to add a button for the user to manually click "refresh"?